# How can you include a ViewPager inside a ListView header

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I want to be able to put a "image slider" in the header of a list view. So, the user can swipe through images, then when they start to scroll the page, the slider scrolls out of view.

I have gotten my desired slider with a ViewPager. Now all, I need to do is insert it into the header of the List View, but this seems to be causing me major issues.

I add the pager as such:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_event, listView, false);

FeaturedEventAdapter featuredAdapter = new FeaturedEventAdapter( getFragmentManager() );

pager.setAdapter( featuredAdapter );

listView.addHeaderView( pager );
```

I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

Now, a key thing to note, is that this works perfectly fine if I am displaying it outside of the List View.

Edit: featured_event xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dip">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/car" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: when do you set list adapter?

Comment: I set the listView adapter after I attempt to add the headerView

Comment: can you post the xml for featured_event?

Comment: what is the reason to put childs into the ViewPager? how do you expect to be drawn? By the way, you don't have to put xml schema declaration into every child - only to root.

Comment: leave in xml only this <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dip"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087241/adding-viewpager-as-a-header-to-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

without being able to see your featured_event.xml layout, I'd try this :

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_event);
ViewPager pager = null;
if (root instanceof ViewPager){
    Log.d("TAG", "the root element IS the viewpager");
    pager = root;    
} else {
    Log.d("TAG", "pager is not the root element in featured_event.xml, lets find it");
    pager= (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.myViewPagerIdThatIGaveIt);
}
FeaturedEventAdapter featuredAdapter = new FeaturedEventAdapter( getFragmentManager() );
// add header before adapter
listView.addHeaderView( pager );
pager.setAdapter( featuredAdapter );
```

Comment: I think it must be something to do with my xml. Posted it as an edit.