# adding Viewpager as a header to a listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to program an activity that show a viewpager with some images and listview below with some data .. but my problem is that I can scroll only the listview on the last part of the screen I wanted to make the viewpager scrollable with the listview so I thought about putting it as header .. here's my XMl file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/sectionsList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_bg" />

<include layout="@layout/main_screen_components" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and I write this in my class

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<News> result) {
        Utils.pagerNews(result);
        Utils.listNews(result);

        ImagePagerAdapter pAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(
                appManager.getPagerNews());
        pager.setAdapter(pAdapter);

        View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_screen_components , null , false);

        NewsListAdapter adapter = new NewsListAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                appManager.getListNews());
        listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progress.dismiss();
    }
```

when I run this code it gives me a duplicated pager .. fixed one with the data and an empty one as an header of my listview .. when I remove  which include my pager it crashes when I try to set an adapter to the pager .. any idea ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

just set viewPager's onTouchListener,like this:

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    PointF downP = new PointF();
    PointF curP = new PointF();
    int act = event.getAction();
    if(act == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
      ((ViewGroup) v).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
      if (downP.x == curP.x && downP.y == curP.y) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: @eric I am facing a problem understanding this function. This function regard less of action returns false. And dowp and curP are just initialized but have no change in their values that means x,y of dowp and curP are 0 and so always equal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below custom viewpager class:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
 boolean xScored = false, yScored = false;

 public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
 }

 public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        xScored = false;
        yScored = false;
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
 }

 GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (!yScored && Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY)) {
            xScored = true;
            yScored = false;
        }
        if (xScored) {
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        } else if (!xScored && Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
            xScored = false;
            yScored = true;
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

 };
 GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGestureListener);
}
```