# Hide LinearLayout at top when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/featuredContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/panelpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I already implements **AbsListView.OnScrollListener** to my **ListView** and I can have the Y of first item, but how can I hide the **featuredContent** when scrolling to bottom so I can see ListView in my whole screen?

```
listNews.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        View firstItem = listNews.getChildAt(0);
        int top = (firstItem == null) ? 0 : firstItem.getTop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean when you scroll to bottom right?

Comment: you want to hide linear layout when you scroll to bottom?

Comment: Right, to bottom. Sorry.

Comment: Instead of having a separate view, you could just add your featuredContent as a header to your `ListView` with the `addHeader()` method.

Comment: @AndrewSchuster ok, almost works. Now I can't scroll the `ViewPager` after add to header of `ListView`.

Comment: [You might find this question helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087241/adding-viewpager-as-a-header-to-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.featuredContent);

if (firstVisibleItem == 0)
{
    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

View.Gone will consider that this view never exist. therefore, there will not be a space in its place. unlike View.INVISIBLE that while reserve position empty.